# Wordpress - Custom Fields - How to print 'breaklines'

Tags: wordpress, custom-fields

I create a custom field using this plugin: https://es.wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/

Then, I added this line to output the custom field in the frontend

```
echo '<div>' . get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'my_custom_field', true ) . '</div>';
```

Problem is that the output does not print the breaklines. Then my question is if is there other function to output the custom field so that I can get the 'breaklines' printed in the frontend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use PHP's [nl2br()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) to convert new lines into `<br />` tags:

```
<?php
$foo = "foo isn't\n bar"; //

echo nl2br( $foo );

// Outputs:
//
// foo isn't<br />
// bar
?>
```

... or you can do it the WordPress way and use the [the_content filter hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/the_content/):

```
<?php
$foo = "foo isn't\n bar"; //

echo apply_filters( 'the_content', $foo );

// Outputs:
//
// <p>foo isn't<br />
// bar</p>
?>
```

---

So now your code becomes:

```
echo '<div>' . nl2br( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'my_custom_field', true ) ) . '</div>';
```

or:

```
echo '<div>' . apply_filters( 'the_content', get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'my_custom_field', true ) ) . '</div>';
```